# How to manage a unique DateTime field in a database table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using Visual Studio 2010, Windows XP and SQL Server CE.

I want to make a database table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Logs  
(  
    Id int,  
    ***LogTime datetime***,  
    Register1 smallint,  
    Register2 smallint,  
    Register3 smallint,  
)
```

Id will be primary key and identity.

I have these problems I cannot solve:

1. this table will be populated by ***big bulk inserts*** (even up to 300k records at time), because the "data source" will be a file from an USB plugged into PC. This binary formatted file contains time-ordered logs. My software has to grab it, decode it and prepare the records to be ***added*** to the database.
2. there cannot be duplicated datetimes (2 records with the same datetime) in the db, because eventually a graph will be made from this table's data.

So the first bulk insert will be fine, for example:

```
1, 2013-01-01 12:34:12, 12, 100, 200  
2, 2013-01-01 12:34:24, 13, 100, 212  
3, 2013-01-01 12:34:36, 11, 110, 208  
...  
100, 2013-01-01 14:04:58, 15, 120, 198
```

but the next file to insert will have the old content + other new subsequent records. And I need to insert only the new records (otherways I'm creating record copies).

So
file 1: from january 1 to january 5
file 2: from january 1 to january 8

At the moment I have implemented the database table as a flat binary file, and before inserting, I go find the "insertion point" with O(N) linear scan, then I can append new data.

I would like to use SQL server CE instead of a flat binary file as a data container.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: What happens if you find a record with a timestamp that already exists in the database? Do you want to overwrite the record (i.e. you're doing an upsert) or ignore the record?

Comment: @datadamnation original timestamp comes from an hardware datalogger, that cannot log faster than 2 seconds. So it's impossibile that 2 records (or log) have the same timestamp. And of course, the timestamp is always ascending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention "time-ordered logs", I'm assuming that it's impossible for records you're inserting to ever be from before the last insert. E.g., the dates will **always** be unique and **always** be ascending. (E.g. some program adds a record to the file every 12 seconds.)

In this case, create a variable to hold the most recent date:

```
DECLARE @Last_Datetime DATETIME
```

Then simply create a temp table that matches the schema of the table you're planning on inserting to:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.#Temp_Logs  
(
    LogTime datetime, 
    Register1 smallint,  
    Register2 smallint,  
    Register3 smallint,  
)
```

And bulk insert to that table.

Then grab the most recent record:

```
SELECT @Last_Datetime = MAX(L.LogTime)
FROM dbo.Logs as L
```

Then use `INSERT SELECT` with a `WHERE` clause to move the rows over:

```
INSERT Logs
SELECT
    TL.datetime,
    TL.Register1,
    TL.Register2,
    TL.Register3
FROM dbo.#Temp_Logs AS TL
WHERE TL.datetime > @Last_Datetime
```

Comment: Yes, given that the new log file contains the old records (as opposed to other records that contain similar timestamps), this should work fine.  Although, the variable probably isn't required, and the value can likely be retrieved at the time of the final `INSERT`.

Comment: I believe you're correct, but this avoids doing any kind of aggregate function in the WHERE clause, which is good, especially for the purpose of demonstration.

Comment: Although... hmm - if this isn't being done inside a transaction, it isn't completely safe; the order of the timestamps of the `INSERT`ed rows isn't guaranteed, so things get funny if it fails halfway through.  So... either this needs a transaction, or the `INSERT SELECT` needs an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: SSMS statements are atomic, including `INSERT SELECT`, so by default, if there is a duplicate record, the entire transaction will fail and get rolled back. Transactions are only necessary if you're running more than one statement. While this query is three statements, only the last one actually creates any data, so it's not a problem if the first two commit and the last one fails.

Also, I could be wrong here but I think that even if the dates aren't correct, they will be in the right order, because whatever is writing to the log file is always going to append to the end.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to:
1. take lastLogTimestamp from the database table on PC
2. search lastLogTimestamp in the binary flat file
3. take only the subsequent bytes --> format them and bulk insert them to PC?
With this solution I would make only 1 bulk insert, not 2.

Comment: If you can do that, then yes, it will save your server some work. But can you? Usually a precondition of problems like this is that you can't edit the input file - otherwise, you could just save a copy without the previous dates. Better yet, you could modify the app that generates the file to not include prior dates.

You can't use a WHERE clause in a `BULK INSERT`, so do you have something else in mind?

Comment: I am usign sql server CE 4.0, that does not support defined variables, batch statements, and bulk inserts, but I think I have workaround for all of that. ErikEJ made bulk inserts for SLQ CE, I'm going to try it.

Comment: Awesome, let us know how it turns out!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you bulk insert the data into a staging table (truncate it first), and then insert only new records using an EXCEPT clause.

```
INSERT INTO Logs (LogTime, Register1, Register2, Register3)
SELECT LogTime, Register1, Register2, Register3 FROM LogStaging
EXCEPT
SELECT LogTime, Register1, Register2, Register3 FROM Logs
```